# Coldfusion load session from Id

Tags: coldfusion

Is there any way to load a specific user session by providing the correct value of CFTOKEN and/or CFID?

Something like php's session_id($id) function.

Or some way to change data of an specific session.

I need a webservice that will add or change some information on a specific user session. I know the CFID and CFTOKEN values because I share a subdomain cookie. However applications are on different servers

Comment: Are you looking to get a different session than the one one you are logged in as?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is a java object that coldfusion uses to manage its sessions. You could use it to get info from any active session. If you want to get info, you need to use reflection too so you dont inadvertently extend their session timeout

Comment: I need a webservice that will add or change some information to some user's session. I know the CFID and CFTOKEN values because I share a subdomain cookie. However applications are on different servers

Comment: It´s ok to extend the session timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that it's the best way of doing things, as it uses undocumented code that can change without notice between versions.  But you can use certain methods to access sessions.

```
<cfscript>
    appName = 'zadsApp';
    jSessTracker = CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker');
    appSessions = jSessTracker.getSessionCollection(JavaCast('string', appName));
    targetSession = appSessions[appName & '_' & sessionCFID & '_' & sessionCFTOKEN];
    // Dumping, reading, writing WILL update the last accessed time.
    // There are ways around this if needed...
    WriteDump(targetSession);
    targetSession.something = 'A new value';
</cfscript>
```

Now you mention that this is on a different server, can I just double check that you want a seperate server to change a session on another server?  Without putting any kind of code like the above on that server (the one with the session)?  Although it'd be a heck of a lot easier if the code was on the same server, you might be able to perform code like this remotely using JMX... but I'm sure there must be an easier way to do all of this.

Comment: This is actually what i ended up using. I also found out that the SessionTracker has a getSession method and as a parameter takes exactly that string, so you can access the session directly. Thank you.

Comment: Watch out with the getSession method though.  The one I'd used before (in my CFTracker project) has been removed in CF10.  There are a few other "getSession" methods that take more parameters, just haven't worked out what they want yet.  But worth noting, in case you ever upgrade.

Comment: appSessions[appName & '_' & sessionCFID & '_' & sessionCFTOKEN]; still works?

Comment: Yeah, that'll work as appSessions contains references to all the sessions via their session id (appname_cfid_cftoken).  It's just the getSession method that has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by passing the correct values on the URL, more information available here

http://ruthsarian.wordpress.com/2005/10/03/cf-session-hijacking/

> ColdFusion uses two unique values to keep track of user session
>   information. These values are CFID and CFTOKEN. They are stored as
>   cookies but can also be passed along the URL and inside POST data.
>
> Session variables are a place to store information specific to the
>   user and to the current session (such as whether or not a user is
>   logged in).
>
> It is possible to hijack a user’s session by supplying the correct
>   CFID and CFTOKEN values to the server, either on the URL, or wherever
>   else you want.

What it sounds like you are trying to do is effecitvely described by this post http://old.nabble.com/ColdFusion-9-Session-Replication-td32621620.html which advises against session replication on grounds of high network usage due to it.

Where you are trying to maintain a specific sessions scope across multiple physical servers.  The way I've worked around this in the past is to maintain a database storing the information which needs to be passed between physical servers tied to a UUID.  For this purpose you could just use the CFID/CFTOKEN values as your database PK's, or you could make another PK altogether.  This would then allow you to pass the CFID etc on the URL string, and then if it hits a server which it hasn't so far hit (i.e. no session / session wasn't loaded using those CFID/CFTOKEN) then you can load the variables you need from a database.

**Edit** an alternative non-database method

Firstly set up a script on one server i.e. getSessionData.cfm which returns
the data in the session scope in transportable format i.e. using
    SaveObject() (if on CF9), or maybe SerializeJSON(), something like
    that

```
<!--- on source server, getSessionData.cfm --->
<cfscript>
    WriteOutput(ToBase64(ObjectSave(session)));
</cfscript>
```

Then set up a handler that will request data from the other server
    using a cfhttp request populating CFID/CFTOKEN to access the session, and then pull that data into the session on the new server.

```
<!--- on target server --->
<cfhttp url="http://sourceserver/getSessionData.cfm">
    <!--- Params to pass through CFID/CFTOKEN or any other cookie/url/post params etc --->
</cfhttp>
<cfscript>
    structToImportToSession = ObjectLoad(ToBinary(cfhttp.FileContent));
    for (thisStructKey in structToImportToSession) {
        session[thisStructKey] = structToImportToSession[thisStructKey];
    }   
</cfscript>
```

The problem with this is that I would feel uneasy with this kind of script being on my server in a production environment.  It also means that you will need to know explicitly which physical server the user came from so that you can request the getSessionData.cfm script from the correct server.

This post from Ben Nadel seems to employ a similar principle to update session data, same could be applied for updating it I expect, http://www.bennadel.com/blog/725-Maintaining-Sessions-Across-Multiple-ColdFusion-CFHttp-Requests.htm

Personally I'd still advise the database-drive method as it gives you clearer mechanics by which to purge old sessions etc, however this second option should be viable and give you access to what you need.

Comment: This is want I want to do, however I don't see the point of making another table and querying the database. If the session information is already stored elsewhere can't I just load it using the CFID and CFTOKEN and send some of it back? That's why i mentioned php's session_id($id) using that and supplying a valid session uid populates all the session variables with the correct info using the default session management.

Comment: The session information is stored on a physical server.  You wish to access it on another physical server.  So one option is to do as I've suggested, and another would be to issue <cfhttp> requests from the target physical server which request data from the source server

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That's why I'm using a Web Service. Want i want to know is how can I load (in the server that stores the session) the session information of a specific session using CFID and CFTOKEN so i can the use that information as the  return values of the web service.

Comment: Ok I see you edited your answer, thats what I need. Any idea on what the getSessionData.cfm shoud contain? How to exactly extract the data? Do you know of any method in the session object that may help? I'm going to use ip filtering to avoid some problems.

Comment: I've added some sample code - you'll need to sort out where you're going to put it, how you're going to pass CFID/CFTOKEN cross-server, security, and the session data loading but fundamentally that logic should do the job

Comment: There is just one missing detail: `ToBase64(ObjectSave(session))`. How do you know that the session object contains the corresponding session data? When did you supply the CFID CFTOKEN info?

Comment: It's not missing, you need to supply the CFID/CFTOKEN data in the <cfhttp> - i added in a CF comment indicating that as I've no idea whether you are handling them as cookie, url, or anything like that.  This in turn requests from the source server and should access the session.  You will need some handling in place for when a session no longer exists i.e. it's timed out, however fundamentally that should do the job.  The default Application session handling deals with accessing the correct session so long as CFID/CFTOKEN are supplied, or should do.

Answer (score 0):

as long as the session isn't expired you can access a session by using the CFID and CFTOKEN in the url

Comment: can you elaborate? You say this isn't what you're looking for, but you're going to try Simon's answer which is the same as mine. If you are looking to change to another session and you know the CFID and CFTOKEN you can add them to the url `?CFID=#yourCFID#&CFTOKEN=#yourCFTOKEN#`

Comment: I've tried this but its not working, It doesn't seem to override the session set in the cookie. Is there any additional configuration I need to consider?

Comment: Setting the CFID / CFTOKEN to the known values won't help unless you're on the same server and you're using the same application name.